# Summarise data, convert to time series and complete missing months with zeros

Tags: r, time-series

I have some transaction data frame with customerId, date(Date class, but separate year and month num cols are available too), value. I need group data by ID and month and do summarise value and convert it to time series for stl function. But some customer did not have transaction in some month and you need for stl have complete order time series and I want it complete with zero values. And for each customer a want complete year-month and calculate trend and seasonal from his first year-month transaction to now. What it easier way to do it?

I tried simple generate for each year-month transaction with zero value and group by and put vector to ts function. But generate rows for 2000 customer is slow. Is a better way?

Simple data:

```
x = data.frame(customerId = c("A","B","A","B","A","B","A","A", "B", "B","A"),
               date = as.Date(c("2018-09-11", "2018-09-12", "2018-09-25", "2018-11-21", "2018-11-21", "2018-12-21", "2019-01-05","2019-02-20","2019-03-05","2019-05-01","2019-05-28")),
               value = runif(11,500,2000))
```

I expect to have time series like this for each cutomer and his year-month range:

```
         Jan     Feb     Mar     Apr     May     Jun     Jul Aug     Sep     Oct     Nov     Dec
2018                                                             3252.00 1948.73    0.00 3614.50
2019    0.00 5588.50    0.00 4973.50 1164.00    0.00    0.00
```

Answer (score 1):

We could do extract `month` and `year` from `date` using `format`. As we want data for all months we convert `month` to `factor` and including all the months in `levels`, count the total `sum` by `year` and `month` and convert the data to wide format using `spread`.

```
library(dplyr)

x %>%
  mutate(month = factor(format(date, "%b"), levels = month.abb), 
         year = format(date, "%Y")) %>%
  group_by(month, year) %>%
  summarise(total = sum(value))  %>%
  tidyr::spread(month, total, fill = 0)

# A tibble: 2 x 8
#  year    Jan   Feb   Mar   May   Sep   Nov   Dec
#  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 2018     0     0     0     0  4055. 2504.  869.
#2 2019   563.  992. 1932. 3374.    0     0     0
```

**data**

```
x <- structure(list(customerId = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"), 
date = structure(c(17785, 17786, 17799, 17856, 17856, 17886, 
17901, 17947, 17960, 18017, 18044), class = "Date"), value = 
c(1180.00123428646, 
1516.3559531793, 1358.95010293461, 654.387023998424, 1849.73745560274, 
869.13160153199, 563.089300296269, 991.881078924052, 1931.75547372084, 
1834.30897409562, 1539.2051092349)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))
```

Comment: this is not working for me https://imgur.com/FmRUlmq. But I think for stl I need ts class, no?

Comment: @ĽubomírSkirka Try to explicitly mention the package name, I think there is namespace conflict `x %>%
  dplyr::mutate(month = factor(format(date, "%b"), levels = month.abb), 
         year = format(date, "%Y")) %>%
  dplyr::group_by(month, year) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(total = sum(value))  %>%
  tidyr::spread(month, total, fill = 0)`